# How to print the corresponding c of the lowest classification error on the validation data

Tags: python, svm, validation

I'm currently measuring the overall classification error for an SVM classifier and I'm varying the regularization value `C`.

In the following code, how can I print in the last line of the `C` value with the lowest error in the validation set?

```
X_train_ = X_train[:, :51949]
X_val_ = X_val[:, :51949]

y1_train = np.where(y_train == 1, 1, -1)
y1_val = np.where(y_val == 1, 1, -1)
penalty =list_

y1val_err_all = []
y1trn_err_all = []

for c in penalty:
    clf_1 = SVC(kernel="linear", C = c).fit(X_train, y1_train)
    y_pred1_trn = clf_1.predict(X_train_)
    y_pred1_val = clf_1.predict(X_val_)
    y1trn_acc=accuracy_score(y1_train, y_pred1_trn)
    y1val_acc=accuracy_score(y1_val, y_pred1_val)
    y1trn_err=1-y1trn_acc
    y1val_err=1-y1val_acc
    y1trn_err_all.append(y1trn_err)
    y1val_err_all.append(y1val_err)
    print("Training Error (c=:"+ str(c) + ") :" , y1trn_err) #round(y1trn_err,6) )
    print("Validation Error (c=:"+ str(c) + ") :" , y1val_err) #round(y1val_err,6) )
y1trn_acc_err = np.array(y1val_err_all)
y1val_acc_err = np.array(y1val_err_all)
print('The Lowest Val Error : ', np.amin(y1val_acc_err))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

You can use `np.argmin` to get the index of the lowest value, then you get that item from `penalty`

```
X_train_ = X_train[:, :51949]
X_val_ = X_val[:, :51949]

y1_train = np.where(y_train == 1, 1, -1)
y1_val = np.where(y_val == 1, 1, -1)
penalty =list_

y1val_err_all = []
y1trn_err_all = []

for c in penalty:
    clf_1 = SVC(kernel="linear", C = c).fit(X_train, y1_train)
    y_pred1_trn = clf_1.predict(X_train_)
    y_pred1_val = clf_1.predict(X_val_)
    y1trn_acc=accuracy_score(y1_train, y_pred1_trn)
    y1val_acc=accuracy_score(y1_val, y_pred1_val)
    y1trn_err=1-y1trn_acc
    y1val_err=1-y1val_acc
    y1trn_err_all.append(y1trn_err)
    y1val_err_all.append(y1val_err)
    print("Training Error (c=:"+ str(c) + ") :" , y1trn_err) #round(y1trn_err,6) )
    print("Validation Error (c=:"+ str(c) + ") :" , y1val_err) #round(y1val_err,6) )
y1trn_acc_err = np.array(y1val_err_all)
y1val_acc_err = np.array(y1val_err_all)
print(f'The Lowest Val Error : {np.min(y1val_acc_err)}')
print(f'The C with the Lowest Val Error : {penalty[np.argmin(y1val_acc_err)]}')
```